# How can I create a rectangle grid over a polygon ( segmented region)?

Tags: python-3.x, grid, gis, patch, sampling

I need to plot a rectangle grid over a polygon (I have an array of Edge points ) that is segmented region of an whole slide image...

size of ever rectangle or patch  = 256
polygon of edge point = [(x,y),(x,y),(x,y)...,(x,y)]

[image: my input is like this image]

[image: I need this output]

I tried some ways like
"FishNet" but it was for GIS Maps ... i couldnt use it for my image ...

and some ways... "meshgrid in numpy" and "tiling library", ... , but I couldn't solve it .